# C++ Code in Objective-C for iOS

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

Schleife.h

```
#ifndef __CPlusPlusTest__Schleife__
#define __CPlusPlusTest__Schleife__

#include <iostream>
class Schleife;
#endif /* defined(__CPlusPlusTest__Schleife__) */
```

Schleife.cpp

```
#include "Schleife.h"

class Schleife
{
public:
    int addition(int,int);

private:
    int ergebnis;
};


int Schleife::addition(int a,int b)
{
    ergebnis = a +b;
    return ergebnis;
}
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "Schleife.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

ViewController.mm

```
#import "ViewController.h"



@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     Schleife *schleife = new Schleife();
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Whats Wrong?

I got the Error Message:
"ViewController.mm:22:31: Allocation of incomplete type 'Schleife'"

I don't understand what I did wrong. I want just implement C++ Code in my App. So I started with a easy example but it doesn't work...
Can you help me?
I know its maybe a easy Questions but I can't find the mistake...

Comment: i'm not sure but maybe you should put Schleife class declaration into Schleife.h?

Comment: I'm actually sure that without seeing the declaration of that class, neither Objective-C++ nor plain old C++ would be able to compile the new () call nor access any methods of the C++ class. This is nothing particular to Objective-C. That's what header files are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schleife.h should have this code instead of the cpp file

```
class Schleife
{
public:
    int addition(int,int);

private:
    int ergebnis;
};
```

you will also need to include #include "Schleife.h" in your ViewController.mm

Comment: but How i can use this return in my ObjC Code?

`int ergebnis = schleife::addition(10, 20);`
`NSLog(@"%d",Ergebnis);`

i got this error Message: **ViewController.mm:23:20: Use of undeclared identifier 'schleife'; did you mean 'Schleife'?**

and 

**ViewController.mm:23:30: Call to non-static member function without an object argument**

Comment: You can safely use this in your mm file, there should be no issues. What you need to do is use the mm file as a bridge between the cpp and the m world.

Comment: like a bridge? but How i get the cpp Types convert to ObjC Types

Comment: Primitive types can convert. the Classes do not convert at all. let me try to elaborate further in my answer

Comment: Looking at your code, you are missing  #include "Schleife.h" in your mm file

Comment: its in "ViewController.h"